# Hyper-V will not connect to local computer on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I'm trying to use Hyper-V on Win10 Pro.  I've activated it in the Windows Features:
[image]

The service is running:
[image]

But when I start the Manager, my computer is not listed under Actions and choosing Connect to Servicer|Local Computer, I get an error saying "An error occured while attempting to connect to server "[mycomputer]". Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running....Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on your computer '[mycomputer]' because the object was not found...."

Any suggestions on how to fix this?